# Incorrect Created Date in Salesforce Report

Tags: soql, reporting, timezone

I have a report in salesforce named Yesterday's Transactions(Type:Opportunities with Transaction).
I have two fields i.e. Transaction Id and Created Date.

My report contains today's date even though I filter it on Created Date = YESTERDAY.

What could be the reason behind this inconsistency? I tried to search about it on the forum but did not find satisfying answer.
Thank you

Comment: Are you seeing records created yesterday's in today's report by the same user as the one who is running the report?

Comment: Which CreatedDate do you want, the opportunity or the transaction?  Make sure the created date field in your filter is from the same object as the one you are displaying.

Comment: @DavidCheng, Yes I am using CreatedDate from the Transaction object. Still I can see the today's records in yesterday's report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the question marked as android-related? If you're using some dedicated integration account to connect, this "user's" timezone might impact what "yesterday" means, at what time his [12 am (midnight)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5) starts compared to your timezone.

Out of the box reports don't show you hours part in "CreatedDate" but compare what you see with a query, maybe try sorting the results, experiment a bit?

```
SELECT Name, CreatedDate, Opportunity__r.Name
FROM Transaction__c
WHERE CreatedDate = YESTERDAY
ORDER BY CreatedDate
```

Comment: I have removed the android-related tag. I think the difference I am getting between the salesforce report and soql query result set is because of the time zone difference. ie. My salesforce account timezone is set to EST. So, it will filter out the results in report based on EST dates.

On the other hand SOQL returns the results in UTC timezone. Let me know if I am correct?

Comment: Yep, that's my understanding too. Reports (and other SF UI in general) silently adjust for user's timezone. But SOQL always returns UTC. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm. If you want - SOQL has built-in function for conversion to running user's preferred timezone: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm

Comment: I have looked into the link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm that you have shared regarding the conversion of timrzone. But, it looks like it only works if we use date function in the SOQL query. For normal query like "SELECT Id,CreatedDate FROM Opportunity WHERE CreatedDate > 2017-11-01T00:00:00Z" it will not work.

Comment: The filter you're using already is supposed to be in UTC, that's what "T" and "Z" mean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209941/what-t-and-z-means-in-date. So yes, for filter part - you need to cast your app's time down to UTC ( I expect your programming language will have a native function for it) & format it as as the "...T...Z" because that's what SOQL expects.. For reading results back - either you reverse the process on all date fields or you wrap them in `convertTimezone()`

Comment: I have one more query regarding this. Does SOQL also convert the timezone of Date field('2017-10-11') not datetime from salesforce to UTC? Because when using only date field in the soql filter we don't use "..T...Z". am I correct?

Comment: Dates are stored without timezone, you should see it as 2017-10-11 even if you flip your user to GMT+14 (if they were stored with time say midday - setting this timezone would probably make them change). But once they end up in your application anything can happen, check your language docs. In the sense in which you're asking JavaScript for example doesn't have "pure Date" variable, it's all related to "seconds since Jan 1st 1970" and this means SOQL results handled in JS are prone to timezone-related "fun".